# is there any compatible version of SonarQube with Java 13

Tags: maven, spring-boot, sonarqube, java-13

I am currently using SonarQube Community Edition version 7.7 on Java 8 JDK using Maven, Iwant to start evaluating OpenJDK 13 . Sonarqube doesn't support OpenJDK 13

Comment: Looking at [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/) page it states: "SonarQube analysis requires version 8+ of the JVM and the SonarQube Server requires version 11+". So did you encounter some issue?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I'm not sure what you mean. It says on the page that it supports openjdk 11. OP is asking for openjdk 13. Are they compatible?

Comment: I have installed JDK 13 recently. It is not running any build properly. If I downgrade JDK 12 it is working fine. I wanted to know is there any specific changes we need to make for JDK 13 to run sonarqube successfully?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/), it says SonarQube only supports JDK11 (Oracle or OpenJDK)